# Flutter Webview Error acquiring assertion; Client is missing required entitlement;

Tags: flutter, plugins, webview, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

For both flutter_webview_plugin.dart' and webview_flutter.dart'

I am getting the following error when I got to certain websites. No errors if I go to youtube or google. How can I find out what required entitlement it is missing?

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281a99f20; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1009b26e0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.347427-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c8938 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10372
2020-08-29 18:09:59.347475-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c8938 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-29 18:09:59.348239-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281bd0900; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x100c99fa0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.348325-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c8960 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10370
2020-08-29 18:09:59.348407-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c8960 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-29 18:09:59.349220-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281a92250; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x100a2bb40; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.349256-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c8988 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10373
2020-08-29 18:09:59.349288-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c8988 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-29 18:09:59.639261-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281a97990; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x100834e10; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.639356-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c91f8 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10372
2020-08-29 18:09:59.639408-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c91f8 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-29 18:09:59.640527-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281a99e90; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1008a19b0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.640571-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c9220 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10370
2020-08-29 18:09:59.640611-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c9220 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-29 18:09:59.641515-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281a96d90; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1008a19b0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-29 18:09:59.641557-0400 Runner[10370:3333538] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10e7c9248 - ProcessAssertion() PID 10370 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 10373
2020-08-29 18:09:59.641599-0400 Runner[10370:3333265] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e7c9248 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```